# How to save to database MySQL/MariaDB using PHP-JQuery?

Tags: php, html, jquery

I want to create a simple website to show form input fields based on select values. Here is my codes:

**index.php**

```
<?php
  include('conn.php');
?>

<!--  For server type field -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>

<script>

// For physical type -------------------------------------
 $(document).ready(function () {
    toggleFieldsPhys(); // call this first so we start out with the correct visibility depending on the selected form values
    // this will call our toggleFields function every time the selection value of our other field changes
    $("#type").change(function () {
        toggleFieldsPhys();
    });

});
// this toggles the visibility of other server
function toggleFieldsPhys() {
    if ($("#type").val() === "physical")
        $("#physical").show();
    else
        $("#physical").hide();
}
// -------------------------------------------------------


// For cloud type ----------------------------------------

 $(document).ready(function () {
    toggleFieldsCloud(); // call this first so we start out with the correct visibility depending on the selected form values
    // this will call our toggleFields function every time the selection value of our other field changes
    $("#type").change(function () {
        toggleFieldsCloud();
    });

});


function toggleFieldsCloud() {
    if ($("#type").val() === "vps")
        $("#vps").show();
    else
        $("#vps").hide();
}

// -------------------------------------------------------



</script>

  <body>
      <center>
        <h1>Add Server</h1>
      <center>
      <form method="POST" action="add_process.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
      <section class="base">
         <div>
          <label>Server Type</label>
          <td>
            <select id="type" name="type" required>
               <option value="">Choose Type</option>
               <option value="physical">Physical</option>
               <option value="vps">VPS Hosting</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </div>


        <div class="input-group" id="physical">
        <fieldset>
            <p>Server Name:
               <input  type="text" name="servername" required />
            </p>
            <p>Manufactur:
               <input  type="text" name="brand" required />
            </p>
            <p>Type:
               <input type="text" name="product" required />
            </p>
            <p>Serial Number:
               <input  type="text" name="sn" required />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
        </div>
<br>
        <div class="input-group" id="vps">
        <fieldset>
                <p>Hosting Name
               <input  type="text" name="hosting" required />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
        </div>
<br>
        <div>
          <label>Processor</label>
          <input type="text" name="processor" autofocus="" required="" />
        </div>

<br>

<br>
        <div>
         <button type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
        </section>
      </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**add_process.php**

```
<?php
include 'conn.php';


$type           = $_POST['type'];
$number         = $_POST['number'];
$servername     = $_POST['servername'];
$brand          = $_POST['brand'];
$product        = $_POST['product'];
$sn             = $_POST['sn'];
$hosting        = $_POST['hosting'];
$processor      = $_POST['processor'];

$query = "INSERT INTO try (type, number, servername, brand, product, sn, hosting, processor ) VALUES ('$type', '$number', '$servername', '$brand', '$product', '$sn', '$hosting', '$processor')";
                  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                  if(!$result){
                      die ("Query Failed: ".mysqli_errno($conn).
                           " - ".mysqli_error($conn));
                  } else {
                    echo "<script>alert('Data Saved');window.location='index.php';</script>";
                  }
```

[image: Output of the index.php]

The problem is when I choose **Physical type**, the **data is saved** to the database. But when I choose ***VPS Hosting***, I ***cannot Save*** to the database because the save button can't be clicked normally.

What should I do if I click VPS Hosting and I fill the form, the data save to the database?

Comment: "because the save button can't be clicked normally" 
what do you mean by that ?

Comment: I mean when I click the Save button when I choose VPS Hosting, the button can not be clicked. But when I choose Physical, it is no problem to click the button.